# How to share a variable between 2 config files?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In `config/config.exs` there’s this:

```
a1 = 123

# [.........]
# using a1 here ....
# key123: a1

import_config("config2.exs)
```

But in `config/config2.exs` the variable `a1` won’t be visible.

Why not? And how to make it visible in `config/config2.exs` too?
**A simple solution, without unnecessary complexity.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use environmental variable to store your value and share it between configs - so in `config/config.exs`:

```
config :myapp, MyApp.Module,
   key123: System.get_env("A1_VAR")

import_config("config2.exs)
```

and in `config/config2.exs` you can retrieve it in the same way.

EDIT

Forgot to mention that if you want to manipulate your declared `a1` variable in the first config - you can use [System.out_env/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12.0/System.html#put_env/2) to "store" it and then of course [System.get_env/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12.0/System.html#get_env/2) to retrieve it in config 2.

Comment: I can't really see another (simple) way than to pass your variable through some kind of "outside" storing mechanism. How about DETS? 
ie: you are initiating your variable in the first config, doing something with it, writing to DETS, in new config retrieving it and using again.

Comment: @Kakaraji could you please explain why are you deleting your comments and voting down valid answers to your questions? How does it help to build a healthy and kind community of Elixir developers?

Answer (score -1):

If `key123` accept an integer, I think it needs to add string to int conversion in config like `System.get_env("A1_VAR") |> String.to_integer()`.